# Call a method every second android

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to call a method every seconds like update in unity3d??
I have tried this: but it give me many error on handler

```
Handler h = new Handler();
int delay = 100; //milliseconds

h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
     //do something
     h.postDelayed(this, delay);
  }
}, delay);
```

Comment: SORRY FOR last 2 lines, it didn't want accept my question

Comment: Beside your question. A second is 1000 milliseconds . Try using an asynctask or a countdowntimer.

Comment: Thats because you should add more detail instead of circumventing the minimum. Like, what is the error?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'Handler'

Comment: isn't important if i use 1000 or 1 or 28471298 miiliseconds, error isnt for that

Comment: Do you have `Handler` imported?

Comment: whats the code to import handler??

Comment: i have AutoImport with all checkbox checked

Comment: Maybe if you posted the error someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java `Threads`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        System.out.println("Run...");
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
            }
         }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
    thread.start();
}
```